# What username does the kubernetes kubelet use when contacting the kubernetes API?

Tags: authentication, authorization, kubernetes

So I've been trying to implement ABAC authorization in the kubernetes API, with the following arguments in my kube-api manifest file.

```
  - --authorization-mode=ABAC
  - --authorization-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/auth/abac-rules.json
```

And the following content in the abac-rulse.json file.

```
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"*",         "nonResourcePath": "*", "readonly": true}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"admin",     "namespace": "*",              "resource": "*",         "apiGroup": "*"                   }}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"scheduler", "apiGroup": "*", "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "readonly": false}}
{"apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1", "kind": "Policy", "spec": {"user":"kubelet", "apiGroup": "*",   "namespace": "*", "resource": "*", "readonly": false }}
```

However, the kubelets can't seem to connect to the api servers. I read that the username is taken from the CN field of the -subject in the certificate used to authenticate the connection, [see here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/). In this case that's the fqdn of the hose, i've tried that too with no luck.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Cheers in advance

Edit:

I'm using Kubernetes version 1.2.2, both kubectl and hyperkube docker image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the answer, documenting here for anyone else having the same issue with ABAC.

The kubelet user is define in the worker configuration, which in my case is a yaml file which i store here - `/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml`, the content of which is shown below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: default
  cluster:
    server: https://10.96.17.34:8443
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker-key.pem
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: kubelet
  name: kubelet-context
current-context: kubelet-context
```

So the user it's connecting with is `kubelet`.

In my case I had create my certificates with the CN=${MINION_FQDN}, and since this did not match "kubelet" then the ABAC policies weren't met. I regenerated my certifcates with the following arguments and now the nodes authenticate succesfully :)

```
# Create worker key
openssl genrsa -out $OUT/${WORKER_HOSTNAME}/worker-key.pem 2048
#Creating Worker CSR...
WORKER_FQDN=${WORKER_FQDN} WORKER_IP=${WORKER_IP} openssl req -new -key $OUT/${WORKER_HOSTNAME}/worker-key.pem -out $OUT/${WORKER_HOSTNAME}/worker.csr -subj "/CN=kubelet" -config $SSL_CONFIG
# Creating Worker Cert
WORKER_FQDN=${WORKER_FQDN} WORKER_IP=${WORKER_IP} openssl x509 -req -in $OUT/${WORKER_HOSTNAME}/worker.csr -CA $CA/ca.pem -CAkey $CA/ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out $OUT/${WORKER_HOSTNAME}/worker.pem -days 365 -extensions v3_req -extfile $SSL_CONFIG
```

The important part of which is this:

```
-subj "/CN=kubelet"
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It certainly helped me. Thanks!